# What is this kind of diagram called?

Tags: data-visualization

I generated a diagram to show the flow through a series of steps. I know I have seen such diagrams before, but none of the search terms I come (flow, hair, line, string, ...) leads me to similar results.

What are images like the following called?
[image]

Comment: What do the axes represent? What are the lines here? What does red vs green indicate?

Comment: I guess it's a good candidate for http://accidental-art.tumblr.com/ ...

Comment: @gung On the x-axis we have time, on the y-axis we have the five steps of a process. Every line is one run through the process. I try to visualize the steps that are responsible for delays, which here show up as horizontal lines. The content of the image is of little relevance to the qustion, though, which pertains to the kind of visualization where a large number of very thin lines is drawn, such that individual lines are barely visible, but clusters of lines can be seen very clearly.